# Joining multiple Keras models

Tags: keras, merge, model

I'm trying to replicate the network described in this link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07492.pdf. I've been able to replicate the patch networks of the model so far, so now I have 9 models of (32,32,3) input size each.

However, the next step is to merge those 9 models into a single one to obtain a single (96,96,3) input network. The idea is that of the 27 neurons of the first layer, the first 3 correspond to the pretrained model of the first patch, and so on. Here is an image of how it should result (each colored row is a different model):
[Final concatenated model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7TSL.png)

In this image, each row before the fully-connected layer represents a previously trained model with the following characteristics:
[(32,32,3) architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTtrF.png)

As you can see, this network analyzes images of (32,32,3). However, the complete model needs to follow this structure that uses a (96,96,3) model:
[(96,96,3) architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztRzA.png)

I already have the (32,32,3) models in their respective hdf5 file, but I do not know how to merge them into a single model to obtain the one of size (96,96,3). I tried using the `concatenate` function of Keras, but I got an error that said that my inputs needed to be tensors.

Here is the code that I used:

```
in1 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch1 = load_model('patch1.hdf5')

in2 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch2 = load_model('patch2.hdf5')

in3 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch3 = load_model('patch3.hdf5')

in4 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch4 = load_model('patch4.hdf5')

in5 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch5 = load_model('patch5.hdf5')

in6 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch6 = load_model('patch6.hdf5')

in7 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch7 = load_model('patch7.hdf5')

in8 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch8 = load_model('patch8.hdf5')

in9 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))

model_patch9 = load_model('patch9.hdf5')

model_final_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([model_patch1, model_patch2,
    model_patch3, model_patch4, model_patch5, model_patch6, model_patch7, 
    model_patch8, model_patch9])

model_final_dense_1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_final_concat)

lsCnn_faces = Model(inputs=[in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7,in8,in9],
                    outputs=model_final_dense_1) lsCnn_faces.summary()
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Always post some code, in this case the model code when asking these questions/

Comment: Also, I don't see any 96,96,3 input based architecture, it seems all of the pooling output is flattened and concatenated into a dense layer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I modified the question to add the code that I used, and I tried to make clearer what the problem is.

Comment: The (96,96,3) architecture looks like it's designed to deal with 96x96 pixel images. A single 96x96 pixel image is not the same as 9 32x32 pixel images glued together in a 96x96 pixel shape. A sensible solution might be to just downsample the 96x96 input to 32x32, and feed it into your current models with your current concatenation method.